# Find file with a File Name pattern

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find files with file Name format `"IMG_dddd.JPG"`.

```
`find ./test -name "IMG_"{0000..9999}.JPG`
```

Currently the error I'm getting looks like this.

find: paths must precede expression: `IMG_0001.JPG`

Usage: `find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brace expansion expands each item in the list into an individual argument.

So your command goes from this

```
find ./test -name "IMG_"{0000..9999}.JPG
```

to this

```
find ./test -name IMG_0000.jpg IMG_0001.jpg .... IMG_9999.JPG
```

and only `IMG_0000.jpg` has the `-name` predicate attached to it so find sees all the other filenames as paths to search and throws an error.

If you want to search for any filename in that range you'll need to construct your command differently.

You should be able to use

```
find ./test -name 'IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG'
```